# css font url stops working when publishing Assets in yii2

Tags: css, yii2

In my css file

```
 @font-face {
             url('fontpu/anmo000-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fontpu/anmo000-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                            }

    .punjabi{

    font-family: 'anmollipiregular';
    }
```

then I registered this in my AppAsset class.

```
public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/punjabi.css',
    ];
```

the `fontpu` folder is in the `web` folder (the web accessible folder which contains index.php).

if I place the css under the `<style>` tags in the `index.php` the font works fine but when publishing asset, it does not load.
 How do I give font's path to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url) :

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

You should simply use the correct relative path :

```
url('../fontpu/anmo000-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fontpu/anmo000-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
```

Comment: tried this. still does not work. I checked the viewsource the link to the published file is `<link href="/blo/web/css/punjabi.css" rel="stylesheet">`.  the font's abolute path is `http://localhost/blo/web/fontpu/anmo000-webfont.woff`

Comment: yes. actual code contains links to all types. .ttf, .woff2, .eot adn .woff

Comment: I closed the window and then loaded it again. and now it works. Was it a caching issue?